# How to pass an empty span object?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdvector, function-parameter, std-span

Is there a way to pass an empty `std::span<int>` to a function?

I have a function like below:

```
bool func( const std::vector<int>& indices )
{
    if ( !indices.empty( ) )
    {
        /* do something */
    }

    ...
}


// when calling it with an empty vector
const bool isAcceptable { func( std::vector<int>( 0 ) ) };
```

And I want to change it to use `std::span` instead of `std::vector` so that it can also get `std::array` and *raw array* as its argument.

Now here:

```
bool func( const std::span<const int> indices )
{
    if ( !indices.empty( ) )
    {
        /* do something */
    }

    ...
}


// when calling it with an empty span
const bool isAcceptable { func( std::span<int>( ) ) }; // Is this valid code?
```

Also does `std::span` properly support all contiguous containers (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::array`, etc.)?

Comment: *Is this valid code?* - Why do you think it might be invalid? `std::span`'s default ctor is documented to create an empty span.

Comment: @Evg So an empty `std::span` does not point to any location, right? Also is creating a temporary span object snd then passing it to the function (like above) the optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: Please define "optimal". To me, it's a good and clear way.

Comment: @Evg Optimal like being efficient (in terms of memory). Anyway, I got it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "*Also does std::span properly support all contiguous containers?*" Not all, this container may also need be `sized_range` since the `span` will use `ranges::size` to get its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::span`'s default constuctor is [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) as:

> `constexpr span() noexcept;`
>
> Constructs an empty span whose `data() == nullptr` and `size() == 0`.

Hence, passing a default constructed `std::span<int>()` is well-defined. Calling `empty()` on it is guaranteed to return `true`.

---

> Does `std::span` properly support all contiguous containers (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::array`, etc.)?

Basically, `std::span` can be constructed from anything that models a contiguous and sized range:

> ```
> template<class R>
> explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
> constexpr span(R&& range);
> ```
>
> Constructs a span that is a view over the range range; the resulting span has `size() == std::ranges::size(range)` and `data() == std::ranges::data(range)`.

In particular, `std::vector` does satisfy these requirements.

For C-style arrays and `std::array` there are special constructors (to harness their compile-time size):

> ```
> template<std::size_t N>
> constexpr span(element_type (&arr)[N]) noexcept;
> template<class U, std::size_t N>
> constexpr span(std::array<U, N>& arr) noexcept;
> template<class U, std::size_t N>
> constexpr span(const std::array<U, N>& arr) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Constructs a span that is a view over the array `arr`; the resulting span has `size() == N` and `data() == std::data(arr)`.

Comment: Well, this is what I was looking for. But another question of mine is that what does this mean? "This overload participates in overload resolution only if extent == 0 || extent == std::dynamic_extent." This is from the same link you provided. I mean what is `extent`?

Comment: So is `std::span` useless when it comes to associative containers?

Comment: @digito_evo `extent` is a second template parameter of `std::span<T, extent>` that is defaulted to `std::dynamic_extent`. `std::span` can have either a compile-time size (= `extent != std::dynamic_extent`) or run-time size (when `extent = std::dynamic_extent`).

Comment: @digito_evo Basically, yes. Associative containers are node-based and hence are not contiguous. You can form a span of size 1 to each particular element, though. ;)

Comment: Nice, so e.g. when a `std::array<int, 50>` is passed to my function, then `extent != std::dynamic_extent`?

Comment: @digito_evo No. Your function is declared as taking `std::span<const int>`, so `extent` is always equal to `std::dynamic_extent`.

Comment: I see, so there is no way in this particular case to make it compile-time since it also needs to accept vectors.

Comment: @digito_evo With that signature, no.